# Updating column in mysql database using HTML input button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, twig

I have a MySQL table for storing users with columns for exercises (ex1 & ex2) that should go from 0 - 10 depending on which question a user has completed. For example, if a user has completed question 4 in exercise one ex1 would say 4. I have the rest of the site set up so that a user can't move access ex2 unless ex1 is 10.

this is a shortened example of my users table:

```
id | firstname | ex1 | ex2
---------------------------
 1 |  example  |  0  |  0
```

My questions use a form using JQuery to check a users answer and uses bootbox to give information to the user such as why they haven't completed the question correctly.

```
{% block main %}
    <section class="row">
        <article class="ml-auto col-md-8 mr-auto">
            <p>Put the corresponding digit next to the French word.<br>We've completed the first one for you.</p>
            <form id="uanswer" method="get">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer1" name="answer1" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>trois</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer2" name="answer2" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>six</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer3" name="answer3" value="1" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>un</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer4" name="answer4" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>deux</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer5" name="answer5" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>neuf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer6" name="answer6" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>cinq</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer7" name="answer7" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>dix</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer8" name="answer8" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>quatre</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer9" name="answer9" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>huit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px; text-align:center;"><input type="text" id="answer10" name="answer10" placeholder="*" style="text-align: center; width: 30px;"></td>
                    <td>sept</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Check My Answer" id="useranswer" class="btn btn-large btn-info">
            </form>
        </article>
    </section>
{% endblock main %}
```

the JQuery works as it's meant to however I need the database to update if the user gets the correct answer. However, I'm unsure how to go about this.

EDIT
this is my PHP file that is auto generated with my code I have modified.

```
<?php
/**
 * A class that contains code to handle any requests for  
/french_tutorial_one_question_two
 */
/**
 * Support // or /home/french_tutorial_one_question_two
 */
    class french_tutorial_one_question_two extends \Framework\Siteaction
    {
/**
 * Handle french_tutorial_one_question_two operations /
 *
 * @param object    $context    The context object for the site
 *
 * @return string   A template name
 */
        public function handle($context)
        {
            $fd = $context->formdata();
            if ($fd->haspost('useranswer') and ($context->hasstudent())) {
                $u = \R::findOne('user', 'id=?', [$fd->post('useranswer')]);
                $u->ex1 = '1';
                \R::store($u);
                return 'french_tutorial_one_question_two.twig';
            } else {
                return 'error/403.twig';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

this is the exact same code I used in a previous project and it worked perfectly however it won't work now

Comment: Do you have any server side code written?

Comment: You should create some script to work with DB first.

Comment: I am using a PHP framework that automatically connects to the database, in the framework when a page is created it automatically generates a php associated to the page, I shall post the code above in a few seconds.